# Exchanging emails via gmail without revealing real email addresses

Tags: php, email, gmail

I have a php forum which has 50 users and i am wondering how i can exchange emails between members without revealing their real gmail email addresses.The forum works this way.A user 'A' opens a contact form and writes and email and sends it to user 'B'.The email sent is received by user 'B' but does not reveal the real email address of user 'A'.When user 'B' replies,user 'B's' email is not attached anywhere in the email.

Are their existing solutions for this kind of thing.

Comment: So, when User B hits reply, where is the email supposed to go? You can send an email with some fake return address, but you'd have to have a real email address to respond to if you want replies delivered.

Comment: I am having a hardtime rememebering where i saw email address from facebook that i thought was a bit random.My thinking was that these random emails maybe exist and i needed someone in the know to shed some light on theme.

Comment: I still have it on my inbox:update+h4n3Whwej@facebookmail.com Is this by anyway random?.

Comment: While the function of that email address is to hide the user's real email address, there is still a server setup to handle it, then redirect it. Often, too, these email addresses have a limited lifespan (otherwise spammers could just send emails to the "fake" email address).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the PHP `mail()` function.

```
$to = 'send_to@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Some message subject';
$message = 'Oi, what\'s up?';
$headers = "From: Bob < some_other_email@gmail.com>\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```